# Choosing dynamically elements (POS) - selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm struggling with problem about finding elements which are dynamically changing. Our project is, in general, Point of Sales interface with list of categories on top, list of the products on the left and basket on the right.

**HTLM snippet** for one of the category: **Top section (with categories):**

```
<div class="nav-button-container" tabindex="-1" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;"><button class="nav-button nav-button-inactive" style="color: rgb(243, 235, 230); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Kotzonet</button></div>
<button class="nav-button nav-button-inactive" style="color: rgb(243, 235, 230); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Kotzonet</button>
```

and the **xPath**:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button
```

Class is changing base on the selection, if specific category is selected, ending has "active" label, rest of the categories has "inactive". In my opinion, value (text input) of the category might be important to be used in order to find it somehow. Right after opening the POS, it points on "Favorite' category (means that other categories are inactive).

Can you give me any advises?

Comment: Try `//button[.="Kotzonet"]`

Comment: @Andersson Unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: Why do you want to `finding elements`? What do you want to do next with the element with text as **Kotzonet**? Does the element appears being `selected` and `unselected` both states? Or always appears as `unselected`?

Comment: @DebanjanB First of all, I would like to choose specific category (like: e.g. "Kotzone"). If user press on particular category then detailed window (with products) will open. That's the first step, then I want to type on product to move it to the basket and than assert somehow

Comment: @DebanjanB When the user opens the POS, category is set to "Favourite" category. It always appears as unseletec/ inactive

Comment: shared HTML is for specific category ? then you want to type something and select that thing? A screenshot would give more clarity

Comment: @cruisepandey I've enclosed an image :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the button with text as **Kotzonet** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='nav-button nav-button-inactive' and contains(.,'Kotzonet')]")).Click();
```

Comment: I've just enclosed an image with HTML

Comment: @Kermi The reason for `enclosed an image with HTML`? I think I have provided you a solution already. Let me know the status.

Comment: Someone asked me to do so, thought it will be easier to provide further help. I've typed the code and I'm able to open it, but nothing happens, however test is passed (green)...

Comment: Within the question you have provided the HTML for the element with text as **Kotzonet** where as in the updated snap you are emphasising on the element with text as **TOP**. Don't confuse the steps you are trying to _Automate_.

Comment: Could you please tell me what does it mean inside "contains" bracket? I mean ".," ?

Comment: @Kermi (.) stands for `String` literals.

Comment: Thank you, I'm surfing the internet in order to find information about css selectors/ xpaths.... It's quite urgent and I'm not as experienced as I wish to be :(